# .bcfzip file is imported by software only if recompressed. File content remains the same

Tags: xml, zip, compression, bcftools

I am testing interoperability between two softwares and need a file exported from one to be read by other. The file consists of some xml and jpg files compressed in a .zip format (extensions generated by the programs are .bcf and .bcfzip). As far as content goes, the xml files generated by one have the same information as the ones generated by the other software. Nonetheless, when I change its extension from .bcfzip to .bcf in order to it be read by the other software, it doesn't work. If I take the xml files out and compress them again inside the .bcf, it is imported perfectly.Is there any metadata or compression encoding that can be causing this?

Unfortunately I do not have access to any of the code generating these files, so I'm looking  for ways to verify what might be causing this comparing the two files.

Comment: Write ".bcfzip" in the title.

Comment: How, exactly, do you "compress them again inside the .bcf"?